# Display data in dynamically created div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, database

I want to display data function name and function description from database and display it in div which will be created dynamically using jquery. How can I display data with dynamic div using jquery...
code for dynamically created div is:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'FunctionListing.aspx/CountFunction',
                data: "{}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert(result.d);
                    for (var i = 1; i <= result.d; i++) {
                        $('body').append("<div id='div" + i + "' />");
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: So whats happening, whats error? Show us called method

Comment: Does 'FunctionListing.aspx/CountFunction' return only number of functions? May be you should return list of functions names and descriptions from db?

Comment: What does the POST request return?

Comment: .append is pretty slow, it is better to creat a `html` variable and add your html. When the for loop is finished append all the HTML at once.

Comment: Just a side note, try and use Console.log(result) rather than alert when debugging your code.

Comment: You should consider using Knockout.js, it really simplifies the process of bringing your Json data into your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType :"json"
Not datatype :"json"
```

Hope, it'll helps you.